# How to change the viewFlipper's initial image

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want my ViewFlipper to start displaying images from the position value what I provide. How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the setDisplayedChild(n) method for that.

Comment: But I get only blank screen if i provide this statement.

Comment: Sorry my friend. I was missing a line. viewFlipper.addView(image,i); I have added this line also. So now its working without problem. Thanks for your help.